# Windows Script - create script to copy a file and paste in a new network location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a script that essentially runs on a daily basis which copies a file from one network location and pastes into another network location.

Could somebody please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you ok with using a Windows batch file and Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Windows Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file that is called nightly from [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx). The [Copy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/240268) command is what I use most.

```
SET oldLocation=\\OldServer\C$\test.txt
SET newLocation=\\NewServer\C$\test.txt
copy %newLocation% %oldLocation%
```

You would schedule the task and place the batch file on the same server. Either server will work for running the command as long as the user set to run the batch has the proper permissions on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off

echo %date% %time% >> batch.log
echo START ----- >> batch.log

net use x: /delete /Y >> batch.log
net use x: \\<server>\<share> <password> /user:<domain>\<name> /persistant:yes >> batch.log
net use z: /delete /Y >> batch.log
net use z: \\<server>\<share> <password> /user:<domain>\<name> /persistant:yes >> batch.log

xcopy x:\<filename> z:\<filename> >> batch.log

exit
```

I would suggest using xcopy any time you are copying to or from a network location. This helps make sure files in use are still copied and will save you from errors associated with such behavior.

Also adding in the echos for date/time/start and the >> batch.log create a log file that you can search for errors through and know when they happened.

I personally add in the "net use /delete /Y" each time before I set up a network location. In my experience that helps avoid errors dealing with too many resources being used by the same user. Also it is just a cleaner way of doing it.

Eric S's suggestion to use Task Scheduler is a good one. Make sure you set it as such:

- Preferences to run with an admin level account - i.e. highest
  privileges.
- To run regardless of the user being logged on.
- Also set it to terminate if it it runs for more than an allotted time.

Hope this helps.